# Huggingface Trainer, How to setup Cross-Batch MNR loss function

Tags: pytorch, parallel-processing, gpu, huggingface-transformers, torch

When using Transformers package's Trainer, trying to figure out how to have gpu communication in DDP/ multi-gpu setups. Specifically trying to implement cross-batch multiple negative ranking (mnr)  loss

Ideally i want to do `model(inputs)` on each gpu. Gather outputs and do a single call to a loss function rather than n_gpu calls

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving by using `all_reduce`:

```
def distributed_cat(self, tensor):
    arr = [torch.zeros_like(tensor) if i != self.args.local_rank else tensor for i in range(torch.distributed.get_world_size())]
    arr = torch.stack(arr, dim=0)
    torch.distributed.all_reduce(arr, op=torch.distributed.ReduceOp.SUM)
    return arr.flatten(end_dim=1)
```